# Don't know why the length is undefined

Tags: javascript, algorithm, mergesort

I am not sure why, but for some reason when I execute the code it says that the length of the array right is undefined, but why is right undefined? In the execution of this code, I get this error:

" while (result.length < (left.length + right.length)) {
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

```
function merge(left, right) {
  var result = [], iLeft = 0, iRight = 0;

  while (result.length < (left.length + right.length)) {
    if (iLeft === left.length) result = result.concat(right.slice(iRight));
    else if (iRight === right.length) result = result.concat(left.slice(iLeft));
    else if (left[iLeft] <= right[iRight]) result.push(left[iLeft++]);
    else result.push(right[iRight++]);
  }
  return result;
}


function mergeSortRecursive (array) {
  // base case
  if (array.length <= 1) return array;

  // divide and conquer!!
  var leftHalf = array.slice(0, array.length/2);
  var rightHalf = array.slice(array.length/2);
  var leftSorted = mergeSortRecursive(leftHalf);
  var rightSorted = mergeSortRecursive(rightHalf);

  // merge subarrays
  return merge(leftSorted, rightSorted);
};

merge(sampleArr); 
console.log(sampleArr);
```

Comment: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` means that whatever you call `.length` is undefined, not the `length` property itself.

Comment: If you don't have a second array in `merge()`, `right` is `undefined` and it will throw an error. Try `merge([1, 2], [2, 3])`, it works. Voted to close.

Comment: `merge` takes two arguments : `merge(left, right)`. But you're calling it with one argument : `merge(sampleArr)`. So, the second argument (`right`) is undefined. Hence the error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Comment: @JeremyThille oh i got it, thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

When calling the `merge` function, you are not supplying the needed parameters, as in it's declaration you ask for two parameters, and when using it, you are supplying one only, as stated by [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille).

Plus, I would recommend the use of `let` instead of `var`, as it makes variables more secure to work limiting it's scope to the block.